# how to make an api protected in SSO implementation using fastapi

Tags: python, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, fastapi

I have written a fastapi web service, which works as service provider and gets authenticated with Okta Single sign on idp  using pysaml2 libraries. The login functionality works as expected. On successful saml response from okta idp, I get user attributes. My problem is how to make an api protected after that, so that user can access the given API only when he is authenticated from IDP.

I have some flask implementation for this, eg okta-pysaml2-example on GitHub. However, this is implemented in flask and use flask-login for API protection. But I could not get something similar to that in fastapi.

```
import json
import fastapi
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from fastapi import APIRouter
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse, RedirectResponse, PlainTextResponse
from fastapi import Request

from saml2 import (
    BINDING_HTTP_POST,
    BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT,
    entity,
)
from saml2.client import Saml2Client
from saml2.s_utils import rndstr
from saml2.config import Config as Saml2Config

import requests
import logging

sso_router = sso = APIRouter()

uid2user = {}           # global variable to keep user object

class User(object):
    def __init__(self, name_id, data, saml_response):
        self.name_id = name_id
        self.data = data
        self.response = saml_response

    @property
    def authn_statement(self):
        xml_doc = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(
            str(self.response.assertion.authn_statement[0])
        )
        return xml_doc.toprettyxml()


def _expiration(timeout, tformat=None):
    # Wed, 06-Jun-2012 01:34:34 GMT
    if not tformat:
        tformat = "%a, %d-%b-%Y %T GMT"

    if timeout == "now":
        return time_util.instant(tformat)
    else:
        # validity time should match lifetime of assertions
        return time_util.in_a_while(minutes=timeout, format=tformat)

metadata_url_for = {
    # For testing with http://saml.oktadev.com use the following:
    #'okta': 'https://dev-68931166.okta.com/app/exk384pyifILOYpUY5d7/sso/saml/metadata',
    'okta': 'https://saml-bird.daad.com/saml2/idp/metadata.php',
    }


def saml_client_for(idp_name=None):
    '''
    Given the name of an IdP, return a configuation.
    The configuration is a hash for use by saml2.config.Config
    '''

    if idp_name not in metadata_url_for:
        raise Exception("Settings for IDP '{}' not found".format(idp_name))
    rv = requests.get(metadata_url_for[idp_name])

    settings = {
        'entityid': 'https://example.com/sp.xml',
        'metadata': {
            'inline': [rv.text],
            },
        'service': {
            'sp': {
                'endpoints': {
                    'assertion_consumer_service': [
                        ("http://example.com/api/saml/sso/okta", BINDING_HTTP_POST),
                        ("https://example.com/api/saml/sso/okta", BINDING_HTTP_POST)
                    ],
                    "single_logout_service": [
                        ("http://example.com/api/saml/slo/okta", BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT),
                        ("http://example.com/api/saml/slo/okta", BINDING_HTTP_POST),
                    ],
                },
                "required_attributes": ['displayName','mail',],
                "metadata_key_usage" : "both",
                "enc_cert": "use",                               
                'allow_unsolicited': True,                              
                'authn_requests_signed': False,
                'logout_requests_signed': False,
                'want_assertions_signed': True,
                'want_response_signed': False,
            },
        },        
        "key_file": "/app/pki/mykey.pem",        
        "cert_file": "/app/pki/mycert.pem",
        "xmlsec_binary": '/usr/bin/xmlsec1',        
        'encryption_keypairs': [
          {
              'key_file': "/app/pki/mykey.pem",
              'cert_file': "/app/pki/mycert.pem",
          },
        ],
    }
    spConfig = Saml2Config()
    spConfig.load(settings)
    spConfig.allow_unknown_attributes = True
    saml_client = Saml2Client(config=spConfig)
    return saml_client

@sso.post("/saml/sso/okta")
async def idp_initiated(request: Request):
    print("In idp initiated...")
    idp_name = 'okta'
    saml_client = saml_client_for(idp_name)
    form = await request.form()
    authn_response = saml_client.parse_authn_request_response(
        form.get('SAMLResponse'),
        entity.BINDING_HTTP_POST)
    

    authn_response.get_identity()
    user = User(authn_response.name_id, authn_response.ava, authn_response)
    request.session["user_name_id"] = str(user.name_id)
    user_store = {'first_name': authn_response.ava['displayName'][0], 'last_name': authn_response.ava['displayName'][0], 'user_name': authn_response.ava['cn'][0]}  
    #resp = JSONResponse(user_store)
    resp = RedirectResponse("https://example.com/home")
    uid = rndstr(32)
    uid2user[uid] = user
    resp.set_cookie(key='spauthn', value=authn_response.name_id, httponly=True,expires=1800)  
    resp.status_code = 302
    return resp


@sso.get("/saml/login/okta")
def sp_initiated():
    print("In sp initiated...")
    idp_name = 'okta'
    saml_client = saml_client_for(idp_name)
    reqid, info = saml_client.prepare_for_authenticate()

    redirect_url = None
    # Select the IdP URL to send the AuthN request to
    for key, value in info['headers']:
        if key == 'Location':
            redirect_url = value
    response = fastapi.responses.RedirectResponse(redirect_url)
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store'
    response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
    return response

@app.get("/protected_api")
async def protected_api():         # ------------->   how to make this api protected so that only logged user can access this.    
    return "Hi! How are you? You are in a protected Zone."
```